# Получение JSON'а с другого домена и ошибка CORS

Tags: jquery

Прошу помочь разобраться.

Есть ссылка, там лежит json.

Надо посредством ajax забрать данные на jq.
Делаю запрос, как учат, получаю ошибку:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'тут ссылка на ресурс' from origin 'тут ссылка на локалхост' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Гугл говорит, что HTTP заголовок прописать.
Как я понял в файле .htaccess надо добавить записать:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Сделав это, получаю 500. Другой записи в этом файле нет.

А теперь собственно вопрос: в чем ошибка? Можно разжевать, так как много искал в интернете на эту тему, половину не понял.

Comment: у .htaccess синтаксис другой. Надо: Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: попробовал ваш вариант, такая же ошибка.

Я тут нагуглил и у меня сложить впечатление, что эту записать надо не у меня на проекте делать, а там, откуда я беру данные json. На сколько это правильное суждение?

Comment: эта запись должна быть на стороне откуда берутся данные

Comment: тогда тут я ничего не могу сделать :( у меня тестовое задание и эту ссылку мне дали, и сказали использоваться только jq